# How to avoid async.waterfall "TypeError: Cannot read property of undefined"?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I am working on an async.waterfall that I am unsure of how to avoid: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'MediaUrl' of undefined". This TypeError doesn't occur each time the script is run.

The flow is as follows:

1. getName (randomly chooses a name from a list of names
2. searchImage (uses the Bing search API to search photographs associated with that name
3. processBotdata (takes the results from Bing and randomly chooses one of the search results)

Step 3 is where the issue occurs:

```
function processBotdata (searchData, callback) {

    var photographer = searchData.photographer // the search name
    var array        = searchData.array; // search results from bing
    var randomIndex  = Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length);
    var mediaUrl     = array[randomIndex].MediaUrl; // TypeError here!
    var sourceUrl       = array[randomIndex].SourceUrl;
    var searchData         = {
                           photographer,
                           mediaUrl,
                           sourceUrl
                          };
    fs.readFile('results.json', function (err, data) {
    var json = JSON.parse(data);
    json.push(['search results for ' + photographer + ': ',
                              'mediaUrl: ' + searchData.mediaUrl,
                              'sourceUrl: ' + searchData.sourceUrl]);

    fs.writeFile("results.json", JSON.stringify(json, null, "\t"));
    console.log(' ==========> searchData appended to results.json file...')
    });
    console.log(' ==========> searchData has now been processed for upcoming tweet...');
    setTimeout(function() {
      callback(null, searchData);
      console.log(searchData);
    }, 5000);
}
```

I implemented a `setTimeout` for this function hoping that would resolve the issue. My thinking was that the Bing results `searchData.array` was not yet available to be processed, i.e. randomized and selected in this function. As I am new to Node.js and JavaScript I am unsure of my programming error here. I saw this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8023591/node-js-async-foreach-cannot-read-property-value-of-undefined) and I am wondering if it is related to the Bing Search Array which returns the top 50 results.

Update: here is how the `async.waterfall` is called:

```
async.waterfall([
    getName,
    async.retryable([opts = {times: 5, interval: 500}], searchImage),
    async.retryable([opts = {times: 3, interval: 1000}], processBotdata),
    async.retryable([opts = {times: 3, interval: 500}], getImage)
],
function(error, result) {
    if (error) {
      console.error(error);
      return;
      }
});
```

Comment: How are you calling this function `processBotdata`? Maybe you are calling a callback before the result can be acquired.

Comment: I updated my original post to help clarify. I am using the required pattern here https://github.com/caolan/async#waterfall

Comment: What does a `console.log()` on `searchData` returns inside the `processBotdata()` function?

Comment: I forgot to state that this TypeError doesn't occur each time. I will update my post. `console.log()` on `searchData` returns the expected results when the typeError is not thrown, i.e. the photographers name, the mediaUrl, and the sourceUrl from one of the 50 Bing search results returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most obvious possibility is that there is no object at the array index that you're getting. Since you're going after a random index, it makes sense that some random numbers are hitting populated indices, others are not.  Is there any chance that the array is sparse or that the random number you're generating is out of range despite your attempts with Math.floor?

I'd check first in any case, something like:

```
var obj = array[randomIndex];
if(obj){
 // do your stuff
}
```

/*** EDIT FOR NEW INFO ****/

Based on the comment, there's a chance that the Bing results will be an empty array, so the first thing you want to do is to test if that's the case and 'fail fast' to let async.retryable know it should retry:

```
function processBotData(searchData, callback){
    if(!searchData || !searchData.array || !searchData.array.length)
        return callback(new Error('No search results'));
    // continue as before from here
}
```

Note that some folks would prefer my last condition to be something like `searchData.array.length > 0`, but 0 evals as false so I do it this way.

Comment: Since I am new to programming and JavaScript, I don't have an answer to your questions, unfortunately. Here is the search results array: it is rather large so posted here: http://pastebin.com/LRgQfmJj Would this be considered sparse?

Comment: No, doesn't look sparse to me.  A sparse array would be one where you didn't have a value for every index.  (e.g. `[1,2,4,null,17] would be 'sparse' since arr[3] === null).  Still, it'd be a good idea to console.log each of your `randomIndex` values to see what it's coming at.  The only reason you'd get the error you're getting is if `array[randomIndex]` returns null or undefined.  So start debugging those values to see if you can figure out the pattern.

Comment: As a follow up I ran `console.log` on `var randomIndex  = Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length);` and quickly found `randomIndex: 0` `TypeError: Cannot read property 'MediaUrl' of undefined`

Comment: I updated my original question to show how I was able to resolve the issue.

Comment: Glad you were able to resolve it.  Your solution strikes me as slightly odd, though; arrays in JS are 0-indexed, so arr[0] should return the first element in the array.  The pastebin you shared with us didn't have an unusual structure (e.g. [null, {}, {}]), so I'm still curious why you would get that error on the first element.

Comment: I completely agree for the same reasons stated. It is not clear to me why returning a `0` throws the TypeError either. I will update If further testing shows that more than just `0` returns the error.

Comment: So I discovered that when testing this issue, the `TypeError undefined` appears to be coming from Step 2: The Bing API sometimes returns an empty array which in turn results in the `MediaUrl` being `undefined`. Seems like I need to console.log the response and/or body from the Bing search in step 2?

Comment: I'd just include a test in that case.  Since you're doing the retryable bit from async.js, your processBotData can call `callback(error)` anytime it wants to queue up another retry b/c you didn't get the data you wanted.  The failure is probably b/c you are not handling the `undefined` exception in your code.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: Ok great! That makes sense. To clarify: In addition to your update, the above callback in processBotData should also be `error` instead of `null`?

Comment: Not following your clarification?  When  you pass anything non-null to the first parameter of most Node.js callbacks, they are assumed to be receiving an error condition.  That could be a string or an actual error (default as I did, or custom).  If you want to indicate that your code was successful, then the first param should be null, and the second (and subsequent) should be any objects or values you want the calling code to use (e.g. processed bot data).

Comment: apologies - was overthinking what I already should know! I wasn't able to update the return statement you provided above. I believe it needs one additional `)`